# Angular: can't pass value to javascript (.js) file

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, angular-components

1. lets say I have an add(int x, int y) function in test1.js
2. from angular, I will get user inputs (int x, int y)
3. now I need to pass **x** and **y** to **test1.js** and call the add add funtion within in with these 2 variables and get result back in .ts of any component

I have done all of step 1 and 2.

Now for step 3,

a)how can I send 2 values from app.component.ts to that .js file?

b)how to call the funtion written in that .js file with that certain **x** and **y**?

[I mean i know how to call funtion in .js, but now I have to do this from a .ts file with the values]

From here I am running my .js file

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "rest-test3",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "runServer": "node test1.js"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "~9.1.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "install": "^0.13.0",
    "pg": "^8.0.2",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.901.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~9.1.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.3",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~3.8.3"
  }
}
```

You can see in script, I have `runServer` variable that calls the .js file. Now I need to  call a function inside this file with 2 variables. How can I do that?

Comment: please, may i know the reason, why i am down voted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create `test.js` and place that in `/src/assets`

```
    export const add = function (x, y) {
      return x+y;
    }
```

now Import this js file in Angular components 
For now import the file in `app.component.ts`

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { add } from '../assets/myjs.js'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'hallbooking-app';
  constructor() {
    const total = add(5,10);
    console.log(total);
  }

}
```

now you in the js file can be imported in any component and use it